# Loading external JS file, why is it not running?

Tags: javascript, html

My javascript works fine when it's inside the html file, but when I bring it in externally it has trouble running the script, the google developer tools tell me that the file has been loaded in, but I see no evidence of it working.

Can anybody enlighten me to as to why the js file is being loaded but not ran?

Here is the code I'm using to bring it in.

```
function myFunc() {
    var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script= document.createElement('script');
    script.type= 'application/javascript';
    script.src= 'record.js';
    script.async = true;
    head.appendChild(script);
}

<button id='recbtn' onclick="myFunc()">Start Recording</button>
```

Comment: Not without seeing what's inside record.js we can't

Comment: is the javascript file in the same folder as your html?

Comment: @user2961097 From OP: *"the google developer tools tell me that the file has been loaded in"*

Comment: yes, They're in the same folder.
Should I post the entire script? @RGraham ?

Comment: How big is it? If you can post the relevant parts that would be good, if it's a GitHub project you could link to it too.

Comment: 73 lines, It's a little messy...

Comment: 73 lines isn't too bad. And we're used to messy code! :)

Comment: Okay I've put the code in http://jsfiddle.net/7NcKB/ as requested :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your code, you're trying to add this event inside record.js:

```
window.addEventListener('load', onPageLoaded, false);
```

Problem is that chances are the page has already loaded at this stage if the user has clicked on your button to invoke the script. Remove the event listener and call your `onPageLoaded` explicitly:

```
// window.addEventListener('load', onPageLoaded, false); -- Remove this

function onPageLoaded()
{
    ...
}

onPageLoaded(); // Call this function as soon as record.js is loaded
```

Here is an [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7NcKB/1/).